# JSF collapsibleSubTableToggler gives error

Tags: jsf, richfaces, facelets

This is about JSF 1.3. I have a requirement of collapsible/expandable datatable and I tried the solution using `<rich:collapsibleSubTableToggler>` which I found in this site:
http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=subTableToggleControl&skin=blueSky

This is exactly as I wanted and it gives an error given below in run time

> Error Rendering View[/pages/wxyz/xyzzz.xhtml
>   `<rich:collapsibleSubTableToggler>` Tag Library supports namespace: http://richfaces.org/rich, but no tag was defined for name: collapsibleSubTableToggler

Can anybody suggest me a solution or an alternative?

Comment: The referenced site is:
http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=subTableToggleControl&skin=blueSky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http://showcase.richfaces.org site showcases RichFaces 4.0. Your error message indicates that you're using RichFaces 3.x. You should then not be looking at the showcase for RichFaces 4.0, but at the showcase for RichFaces 3.3 http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/actionparam.jsf

In order to use the `rich:collapsibleSubTableToggler`, upgrade to JSF 2.x / RichFaces 4.0.

By the way, JSF 1.3 doesn't exist. Perhaps you meant to say JSF 1.2.

Comment: any alternative or something because i cannot simply change the JSF version in production system :|